# call AsyncTask method from the main method

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, google-directions-api

hye guys, I create an application where it make an HTTPRequest to the google direction web service and it return the JSONobject.

This is my JSONParser.java look like

```
public class JSONParser {
InputStream is = null;
JSONObject jObj = null;
String json = "";

public JSONParser() {
}

public void getJSONFromUrl(final String url, final responseListener target) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());

                int read;
                char[] buff = new char[1024];
                while ((read = inputStreamReader.read(buff)) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append(buff, 0, read);
                }
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException localMalformedURLException) {
                return "";
            } catch (IOException localIOException) {
                return "";
            } finally {
                if (httpURLConnection != null)
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            target.onResponseComplete(result);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

and this is my responseListener.java

```
interface responseListener{
public void onResponseComplete(String response); }
```

I want to call the method getJSONFromURL

```
String response = new JSONParser().getJSONFromUrl(makeURL(startLatitude,startLongitude,endLatitude,endtLongitude),new responseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onResponseComplete(String response) {
        try {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            JSONArray step = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("routes").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs")
                    .getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("steps");

            for (int i = 0; i < step.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String,Object> row = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                row.put("address", step.getJSONObject(i).getString("html_instructions"));
                row.put("start",new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(step.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("start_location").getString("lat")), Double.parseDouble(step.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("start_location").getString("lng"))));
                row.put("end",  new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(step.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("start_location").getString("lat")), Double.parseDouble(step.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("start_location").getString("lng"))));
                list.add(row);

            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

but it keep saying that `Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to String`
any idea on how to solve this ? thank you in advance

Comment: change `getJSONFromUrl` method  return type to `String` instead of `void`

Comment: Try removing the response variable on the start `String response = ` just put `new JSONParser().getJSONFromUrl(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `return type` is `void`

```
public void getJSONFromUrl
```

Change the return type to `String` and `return` a `String`.

In this line

```
String response = new JSONParser().getJSONFromUrl(makeURL(startLatitude,startLongitude,endLatitude,endtLongitude),new responseListener()
```

but the method clearly returns `void`.

As Diego Suárez pointed out in a comment, there is no need for this `response` variable...that is what the callback is for. You can change that to

```
new JSONParser().getJSONFromUrl(makeURL(startLatitude,startLongitude,endLatitude,endtLongitude),new responseListener()
```

And the callback will be initiated when `onPostExecute()` finishes.

Comment: The best solution its returning void and removing the variable "response". It's an async call, and the method returns the String through a callback.

Comment: @DiegoSuárez Yes, that should work. I posted an answer to the error then got distracted before I could look at it more.

Comment: In `onPostExecute()` you have `target.onResponseComplete(result);` which is a callback to your `interface` here `public void onResponseComplete(String response)`. So you just need to run your `AsyncTask` and it should post the `callback`. So that variable `response` that you declare before this line effectively isn't needed

Comment: how am i suppose to do in order to display what is in the ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list variable ??

Comment: i have follow like what u said, the issue now is how to display the value inside the ArrayList list variable ?

Comment: That depends what your problem is now. Is the `ArrayList` being populated correctly? Or you don't know what to do next? Some error? I don't know exactly what the problem is. If you can't get it then its probably better to post a separate question with all of these details.

Answer (score 0):

Because your method

```
 public void getJSONFromUrl(final String url, final responseListener target)
```

has a return type as **void**.

and by below line

```
String response = new JSONParser().getJSONFromUrl(makeURL(startLatitude,startLongitude,endLatitude,endtLongitude),new responseListener() {
```

You are trying to set the this in your **String** response.

You need to change

```
 public String getJSONFromUrl(final String url, final responseListener target)
```

and return a response String from this method.